# HTML5 load a png buffer into a canvas (for streaming purpose)

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, html5-canvas, buffer

Through a websocket, I retrieve a binary buffer of an image in a PNG format ([something like that](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/compression-using-canvas-and-png.html)).

I want to load this PNG buffer into a canvas, and then read the different pixels to read the uncompressed data.

I managed to do it but it is stupid:

```
function onBinaryMessage(/*ArrayBuffer*/ input) {
  input = new Uint8Array(input);

  var str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < input.byteLength; i++)
    str = str + String.fromCharCode(input[i]);

  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(str);

  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  console.log(imgData);
}
```

I have to convert my binary into a string to encode64 this string, and than I affect my image src to this newly created encoded64 string...
The browser have to re-convert this encoded64 data into the original PNG buffer I got...

Is there any way to directement set the canvas buffer?
Or is there any method to better handle streaming?

I think I could use the File API to write the buffer into a temporary file but it would cost a lot to create a file :(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert your input buffer to a Blob instead, obtain an URL for it and use that to draw onto the canvas instead:

```
function onBinaryMessage(input) {

    var blob = new Blob([input], {type: 'image/png'});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
    img.src = url;
}
```

Just note that this will be asynchronous and you would need to provide a callback-mechanism inside the `onload` handler (in any case you really need to do that in your own example as well). But you won't have to convert to base64 etc. which is a relative costly operation.

Also note that `URL.createObjectURL` is currently experimental.

Comment: Many thanks, I works pretty well. I just found the answer few hours ago but you answered faster than me, and with a better answer since you are not creating an image dom element.

createObjectURL works like a charm and I could use a FileReader with readAsDataURL. But createObjectURL must be faster, and it is a synchronous call.

Very nice answer and many thanks ;)

However canvas is still a dom element, I wish I could use a new Canvas such as the new Image you just wrote. (dom is evil)

Comment: @Gb01 good news, you *can* use canvas this way as well. Just use `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');` and no need to attach it to DOM (of course, like image it is still a dom *element*). Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for mentioning the [revokeObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)! It was not obvious to me that blob won't be garbage collected automatically before I saw your answer.