# Convert Topaz Sigweb sigstring to Base64

Tags: canvas, base64, electronic-signature, topaz-signatures

I am working on a mobile application(ionic) where there is a field for user's signature. Users needs to sign with their finger in canvas.

Now this application has web version, where they used topaz sigweb to do this. Now to save signature and to view in both ends i need some kind of conversion.

I checked sigweb's documentation, they save the signature in ASCHII hex format. I am not sure if they are using any kind of internal encryption or not because i can not convert the hex string to any valid base 64.

I am not sure if there are any other way to do that. If anyone has any idea please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can anyone point us what to do?

Comment: In the [doc](https://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/sigweb.pdf) there are `GetSigImageB64()` and `GetSigString()` presumably both used for getting an image representation of the signature as different data formats. No sign of encryption. If you use the former (using callback technique) the string could easily be presented with `var img = new Image();` `img.src = /* result */`. An ASCII hex string should represent binary raw png file, but can also be converted to base64.  [Read more on base64](http://dataurl.net) or [character conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475317)

Comment: @RikkuBölske I did checked that, but you can use that by using their service which comes from their driver. Again these are only accessible from their javascript library not back end library.

Comment: Ok, so it only works in browser, but not javascript back-end? So, now I check out SigWebTablet.js - function GetSigImageB64 and it turns out it obtains image straight from the running service `xhr2.open("GET", baseUri + "SigImage/1", true);` This code does not work in node/ionic back-end out of the box, but it might be easy to fix! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514363/how-to-use-xhr-api-in-node-js

Comment: @RikkuBölske even if i done that how would you host the server? I cannot install the driver on a mobile device, right?

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is a bit old but I'm sure there are plenty of others with the same issue.

I had exactly the same issues when I needed to display the signatures to end users in a standard desktop or mobile browser with no plug-ins or installs required. Spoke to Topaz and there is a an option to run the ActiveX on the server side using the PHP Component Object Model to create the image. Unfortunately, this only works on a Windows server and takes a lot of fiddling with. I only managed to get it working on my test bench and it was useless for my linux production servers. I contacted Topaz again and they said the ONLY other option was a Java applet!?

ActiveX! Java Applets! It's 2019, not 2009! (Sorry, I overdosed on exclamation marks there but Jeez).

In the end I decided to try and decode it myself and eventually came up with this PHP function to create an SVG. The format they use is proprietary (and is actually a bit of a hacky mess) but essentially it is only hex, coordinates and stroke lengths - so it should be easy enough for someone to convert the below to any other platform.

```
//Requires $SigString and accepts optional filename.
//If filename is supplied the image will be written to that file
//If no filename is supplied the SVG image will be returned as a string which can be echoed out directly

function sigstring2svg($SigString, $filename = NULL)
{
    $raw = hex2bin($SigString); //Convert Hex
    $arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $raw); //Split into array
    if ($arr[1] > 0) { //Check if signature is empty
        $coords = array_slice($arr, 2, $arr[0]); //Separate off coordinate pairs
        $lines = array_slice($arr, ($arr[0] + 2), $arr[1]); //Separate off number of coordinates pairs per stroke
        if ($arr[1] == 1) {
            $lines[] = ($arr[0] + 2); //If there is only 1 line the end has to be marked
        }
        $done = 0;
        foreach ($lines as $line => $linevalue) {
            if ($linevalue > $done) {
                $strokes[$line] = array_slice($coords, $done, $linevalue); //Split coordinate pairs into separate strokes
            }
            $done = $linevalue;
        }
        //Split X and Y to calculate the maximum and minimum coordinates on both axis
        $xmax = 0;
        $xmin = 999999;
        $ymax = 0;
        $ymin = 999999;
        foreach ($strokes as $stroke => $xycoords) {
            foreach ($xycoords as $xycoord) {
                $xyc = explode(' ', $xycoord);
                $xy[$stroke]['x'][] = $xyc[0];
                if ($xyc[0] > $xmax) $xmax = $xyc[0];
                if ($xyc[0] < $xmin) $xmin = $xyc[0];
                $xy[$stroke]['y'][] = $xyc[1];
                if ($xyc[1] > $ymax) $ymax = $xyc[1];
                if ($xyc[1] < $ymin) $ymin = $xyc[1];
            }
        }
        //Add in 10 pixel border to allow for stroke
        $xmax += 10;
        $xmin -= 10;
        $ymax += 10;
        $ymin -= 10;
        //Calculate the canvas size and offset out anything below the minimum value to trim whitespace from top and left
        $xmax -= $xmin;
        $ymax -= $ymin;

        //Iterate through each stroke and each coordinate pair to make the points on the stroke to build each polyline as a string array
        foreach ($xy as $lines => $axis) {
            $polylines[$lines] = '<polyline class="sig" points="';
            foreach ($xy[$lines]['x'] as $point => $val) {
                $x = $xy[$lines]['x'][$point];
                $y = $xy[$lines]['y'][$point];
                $polylines[$lines] .= ($x - $xmin) . ',' . ($y - $ymin) . ' ';
            }
            $polylines[$lines] .= '"/>';
        }
        //Build SVG image string
        $image = '
    <svg id="sig" data-name="sig" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' . $xmax . '" height="' . $ymax . '" viewBox="0 0 ' . $xmax . ' ' . $ymax . '">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .sig {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            stroke-linejoin: round;
            stroke-width: 4px;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <title>Signature</title>
      <g>
        ';
        foreach ($polylines as $polyline) {
            $image .= $polyline;
        }
        $image .= '
      </g>
    </svg>';

        //If file name is supplied write to file
        if ($filename) {
            try {
                $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
                fwrite($file, $image);
                fclose($file);
                return $filename;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            //If file name is not supplied return the SVG image as a string
            return $image;
        }
    } else {
        return "Signature is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @scottG i didn't check the thread for a long time. But your answer seems promising, i will definitely try this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I have spent 2 days fiddling with this code, and countless hours (months even) over past 10 years using SigPlus/SigWeb from Topaz.

And when I stumbled upon Scott's answer here, I just had to make it work. Unfortunately, @ScottG made few crucial errors so it didn't work out of the box, and my colleagues that tried it also failed due to lack of documentation. So my answer is 99% built on Scott's code and input, but I am adding:

- sample SigString to work with
- fixes that needed to be done
- requirements
- more comments
- SigString structure explained
- bonus code for HTML5 canvas

Anyway, since the whole story needs to be told, so I am putting the whole example here, not just the (fixed) PHP function.

If you are anxcious to just copy/paste code and move on - skip to actual code. If you want to learn how it works, read it all.

First we need to know that this code (just like Scott's from which it had been built) works only if SigString is neither compressed nor encrypted. If you have previous database of signatures, it's time to convert those to uncompressed/unencrypted ones. This is first step, and reason why others gave up on Scott's code right away. Unfortunately explaining compression/decompression is out of scope of this answer (and I hit character limit, so see my GitHub).

Here is example SigString generated with Topaz tablet, saved by using SetSigCompressionMode(1) ("1" = Lossless compression at a 4 to 1 ratio):

```
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
```

This is same SigString converted to SetSigCompressionMode(0) (no compression):

```
3139370D0A ... <cut - see code below, I've hit a character limit> ... 3132300D0A
```

Bonus: If you really need to save space on disk/in database use this instead of built-in SigWeb/SigPlus compression, down in code there is same example SigString that was uncompressed, and then compressed using PHP's built-in gzdeflate function, you actually get even smaller output this way.

Now, I want to explain the SigString format (base on my sample SigString).
Below is output of raw string, right after hex2bin conversion (cropped for readability):

```
197
4
451 481
450 480
450 479
450 477
450 474
451 470
451 464
452 458
...
787 229
773 227
763 225
758 223
756 223
756 223
0
41
93
120
```

Note we actually have 4 segments here:

- line 1 (sample: 197) is amount of coordinates or "points" we have in
  our signature file, those are number pairs that will start at line 3
- line 2 (sample: 4) is number of lines we have, or better said, number of breaking points we keep, and those are single-number entries at very end of file (in this sample: 0/41/93/120)
- line 3 onwards we have all those (197) lines with coordinate pairs, logically, this will be as small or as long of a list as your signature actually has. To make it absolutely clear, if line 1 said "5" you would have just 5 pairs, if line 1 said "2999" you'd have 2999 pairs
- at end of file we finally have segment with list of those breaking points or end-points that were enumerated by line 2. Again, if line 2 said "3" you would have 3 single-number lines at end of your file, if line 2 said "899" then you would have huge list of 899 single-number lines at end of your file.

As you see from this description, we need to read those first two lines to get started. Later in Scott's code those will be array members, thats arr[0] and arr[1].
Using those two numbers, we can slice the signature into two arrays, one with coordinate pairs, and other with lines, or more correctly - line endings. You can slice it in a number of ways, just keep in mind the format of Sigstring layout.

Using this example we first split the hex2bin result into array, based on provided sample SigString (shortened):

```
["197","4","451 481","450 480", ... ,"758 223","756 223","756 223"]
```

And we finish slicing by creating one other array containing "lines" values (again, length of this array is to be cut as long as second element of original array says to):

```
["0","41","93","120"]
```

Now, in the code you will see I made a fix, so my actuall "lines[]" array prints this:

```
["0","41","93","120","197"]
```

Note that my code-fix added that "197" there at end. That isn't in original signature's end, right? But we still know that from signature's first line, we know it has 197 points, so I just concatenated that to array.
Why do that?

Our example signature is simple two letters - "AP" - and has just 4 lines:

- coordinates 0 through 41
- coordinates 42 through 93
- coordinates 94 through 120
- and... 121 through 197

That last one isn't clearly described, as it should be obvious, it simply goes from previous line's end (120 + 1) till end of coordinate list.
But, well, depending how you do the following steps, your code may or may not need that "197" in lines[] array. For original code to be fixed with minimum changes we need that '197' to be there in array, so that foreach loop can write that last line correctly.
We could've fixed it in several obvious ways:

- if it is last element in for-each, do different code that uses $done + $arr[0]
- we could not need the "lines" as such at all, as you will see in my bonus "HTML5 canvas" code, you don't actually define line start/end as in SVG, you just move your pencil, but sometimes it's moved "on paper" sometimes "in the air"
- etc

As explained, you just need to make sure you use all of your coordinates, and to correct original code this was the easiest way (one-liner) without a more through rewrite.

Knowing what we have now, Scott elected for a solution that included another slicing code. He is slicing our coords[] array to separate lines, well, polylines, that he later outputs to SVG. Due to SVG's format, this is actually the prefered way, or at least I see it as such when looking at how Scott did it and what SVG actually looks like inside HTML as end product.

But unfortunately, original code had 2 mistakes (that took me 2 days to solve :) ).
One mistake was lacking that last line, and depending on your sample signature it may not be obvious. My first sample had just a dot (signature with "i" letters, so whoever signed it did the dots on the "i" literally at the end, so it wasn't noticable at all, just one dot missing). But this "AP" sample I am providing here actually has whole letter "P" as last line, so missing whole letter made it quite obvious. Anyway, I explained how I fixed that so moving on to second issue.

The other bug was that wrong value was used for slice lengths when slicing to segments/polylines. It actually used the last point to slice it, but array_slice PHP function expects (array, starting point, length) and Scott probably expected it to be (array, starting point, ending point). This too was subtle in some signature samples. What essentially happened was some of the points being re-used, but if you write a line on top of a line, it doesn't matter (specially in perfect digital drawing). But! by re-using coordinates, it sometimes extended one line over the path of two or more lines combined, essentially negating what was ment to happen when "pen" was "in the air", and suddenly all signatures looked as if pen was never removed from paper. Eg. the "dot" on the "i" would be a line connecting "i" and the "dot" (or worse even if you wrote "line" and dotted your "i" after last letter, it would connect the dot with "e", now that's making it pop out)

I fixed that, so now it slices something like this (based on output of my example SigString again):

```
line = 1 , linevalue = 41 , done = 0 , linelength = 41
line = 2 , linevalue = 93 , done = 41 , linelength = 52
line = 3 , linevalue = 120 , done = 93 , linelength = 27
line = 4 , linevalue = 197 , done = 120 , linelength = 77
```

I left my sample uncompressed SigString in the code, as well as whole bunch of echos commented out in the code, if you uncomment those you will see this whole process laid out in front of you step by step. And if you comment/uncomment parts of fixed code, you will see same with Scott's version as well, to compare.

I made comments at lines I added, and if it was a change od Scott's line I left his line commented right above my fixed line so you can compare easily.
I did not mark all mine vs. his comments, as those can be skipped anyway, my comments just supplement the explanation or explain my changes.

Here is also a link to my GitHub repo, so you can see whole code there as well, together with complete writeup, as I had to shorten stuff here due to Stack Overflow character limit: https://github.com/luxzg/Topaz

If it's not working for you please leave a comment here or raise an issue at GitHub.

Now on to code finally, sorry it took this long. You can just copy/paste whole thing to http://phpfiddle.org/ to see it in action

--- COPY/PASTE EVERYTHING BELOW TO PHPFIDDLE.ORG ---

```
<?php

//              My changes marked with comment ->   //  fix by LuxZg 08.05.2020.

        //Requires $SigString and accepts optional filename.
        //$SigString has to be UNCOMPRESSED and UNENCRYPTED //  by LuxZg 08.05.2020.
        //If filename is supplied the image will be written to that file
        //If no filename is supplied the SVG image will be returned as a string which can be echoed out directly

        function sigstring2svg($SigString, $filename = NULL)
        {
            $raw = hex2bin($SigString); //Convert Hex
            $raw = str_ireplace(array("\r",'\r'),'', $raw); //  fix by LuxZg 08.05.2020. - hex2bin generated code with \r\n both being used
                //  so after exploding it, the \r would be left, sometimes causing more bugs, but otherwise unseen unless encoded to eg. JSON

//          print the binary format
//          echo '<br><br>First we echo raw string, after hex2bin conversion:<br><br>';
//          echo '<pre>'.$raw.'</pre>'; //  this didn't show \r\n
//          echo '<pre>'.json_encode($raw).'</pre>';    //  this did show \r\n , and after fix now shows just \n, which is now OK for the next step

            $arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $raw);  //Split into array
            if ($arr[1] > 0) { //Check if signature is empty
                    $coords = array_slice($arr, 2, $arr[0]);    //Separate off coordinate pairs // keep in mind SigString format is: coordinate amount - amount of lines - coordinate pairs - end-points of lines
                                                                                                // also get to know your array_slice format: array name - start of slice - length of slice
                    $lines = array_slice($arr, ($arr[0] + 2), $arr[1]); //Separate off number of coordinates pairs per stroke
                    $lines[] = $arr[0]; // fix by LuxZg - 08.05.2020. - later code needs last coordinate added to array, so last slice/SVG segment isn't ommited by mistake

//                  bunch of echoes below, not needed, except to learn/understand, note that to see \r and/or \n you need to use json_encode, that's why I left both, to debug the error Scott's code had
//                  echo '<br><br>Arr[] values:<br><br>';
//                  echo '<pre>';
//                  print_r(array_values($arr));
//                  print_r(json_encode($arr));
//                  echo '</pre>';
//                  echo '<br><br>Coords[] values:<br><br>';
//                  echo '<pre>';
//                  print_r(array_values($coords));
//                  print_r(json_encode($coords));
//                  echo '</pre>';
//                  echo '<pre>';
//                  echo '<br><br>Lines[] values:<br><br>';
//                  print_r(array_values($lines));
//                  print_r(json_encode($lines));
//                  echo '</pre><br><br>';

                    if ($arr[1] == 1) {
                            $lines[] = ($arr[0] + 2);   //If there is only 1 line the end has to be marked
                        }
                    $done = 0;
//                  we always start at zero, it's first member of array, first coordinate we use

                    foreach ($lines as $line => $linevalue) {
                            if ($linevalue > $done) {
                                    $linelength = $linevalue-$done; //  fix by LuxZg 08.05.2020. - we need to know where slice ends, so we use the "done" of previous line as our new start
                                                                    //  and we know where we need to end, so length is simple math
//                                  $strokes[$line] = array_slice($coords, $done, $linevalue);  //Split coordinate pairs into separate strokes  //  end of line is wrong
                                                                                                //  it was including too many lines/coordinates in each iteration, again and again, so I fixed it, left this for comparison
                                    $strokes[$line] = array_slice($coords, $done, $linelength); //Split coordinate pairs into separate strokes  //  fix by LuxZg 08.05.2020. - end of slice is now length of line, as should be
                                }

//                          just an echo to see what's actually happening and also why we needed to add that one last point in our lines[] array earlier
//                          echo "<br>line = ".$line." , linevalue = ".$linevalue." , done = ".$done." , linelength = ".$linelength."<br>";

                            $done = $linevalue; //  we set new value to $done as next line will start from there
                        }

//              I did not touch anything else in this PHP function, from this point below ! SVG drawing code is great!

                    //Split X and Y to calculate the maximum and minimum coordinates on both axis
                    $xmax = 0;
                    $xmin = 999999;
                    $ymax = 0;
                    $ymin = 999999;
                    foreach ($strokes as $stroke => $xycoords) {
                            foreach ($xycoords as $xycoord) {
                                    $xyc = explode(' ', $xycoord);
                                    $xy[$stroke]['x'][] = $xyc[0];
                                    if ($xyc[0] > $xmax) $xmax = $xyc[0];
                                    if ($xyc[0] < $xmin) $xmin = $xyc[0];
                                    $xy[$stroke]['y'][] = $xyc[1];
                                    if ($xyc[1] > $ymax) $ymax = $xyc[1];
                                    if ($xyc[1] < $ymin) $ymin = $xyc[1];
                            }
                    }
                    //Add in 10 pixel border to allow for stroke
                    $xmax += 10;
                    $xmin -= 10;
                    $ymax += 10;
                    $ymin -= 10;
                    //Calculate the canvas size and offset out anything below the minimum value to trim whitespace from top and left
                    $xmax -= $xmin;
                    $ymax -= $ymin;

                    //Iterate through each stroke and each coordinate pair to make the points on the stroke to build each polyline as a string array
                    foreach ($xy as $lines => $axis) {
                            $polylines[$lines] = '<polyline class="sig" points="';
                            foreach ($xy[$lines]['x'] as $point => $val) {
                                    $x = $xy[$lines]['x'][$point];
                                    $y = $xy[$lines]['y'][$point];
                                    $polylines[$lines] .= ($x - $xmin) . ',' . ($y - $ymin) . ' ';
                            }
                            $polylines[$lines] .= '"/>';
                    }

                    //Build SVG image string
                    $image = '
                        <svg id="sig" data-name="sig" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' . $xmax . '" height="' . $ymax . '" viewBox="0 0 ' . $xmax . ' ' . $ymax . '">
                            <defs>
                                <style>
                                    .sig {
                                        fill: none;
                                        stroke: #000;
                                        stroke-linecap: round;
                                        stroke-linejoin: round;
                                        stroke-width: 4px;
                                    }
                                </style>
                            </defs>
                            <title>Signature</title>
                            <g>
                                ';
                                foreach ($polylines as $polyline) {
                                        $image .= $polyline;
                                }
                                $image .= '
                            </g>
                        </svg>';

                    //If file name is supplied write to file
                    if ($filename) {
                            try {
                                    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
                                    fwrite($file, $image);
                                    fclose($file);
                                    return $filename;
                            } catch (Exception $e) {
                                    return false;
                            }
                    } else {
                            //If file name is not supplied return the SVG image as a string
                            return $image;
                    }
                } else {
                        return "Signature is empty";
                }
        }

//              OK to complete the example I actually use the function

        //  this is my simple example "AP" signature, all decompressed and ready to be put through function
        $sigdec = '3139370D0A340D0A343531203438310D0A343530203438300D0A343530203437390D0A343530203437370D0A343530203437340D0A343531203437300D0A343531203436340D0A343532203435380D0A343534203435300D0A343536203434320D0A343539203433330D0A343633203432330D0A343637203431330D0A343731203430330D0A343735203339320D0A343738203338310D0A343830203336390D0A343832203335370D0A343834203334340D0A343835203333310D0A343835203331380D0A343836203330340D0A343836203239310D0A343836203237370D0A343837203236320D0A343837203234380D0A343837203233330D0A343837203231380D0A343837203230340D0A343839203139300D0A343931203137360D0A343934203136330D0A343937203135300D0A353032203133380D0A353036203132370D0A353130203131370D0A353134203130380D0A353137203130320D0A3531382039390D0A3531392039380D0A3531392039380D0A3532312039360D0A3532312039350D0A3532322039340D0A3532332039330D0A3532342039310D0A3532352039310D0A3532362039310D0A3532372039320D0A3532372039340D0A3532382039370D0A353239203130300D0A353330203130350D0A353332203131320D0A353334203131390D0A353337203132370D0A353430203133350D0A353434203134330D0A353438203135330D0A353534203136330D0A353630203137340D0A353637203138380D0A353735203230310D0A353832203231340D0A353838203232380D0A353934203234320D0A353939203235360D0A363034203237300D0A363039203238340D0A363133203239390D0A363136203331330D0A363139203332360D0A363231203334300D0A363233203335340D0A363234203336380D0A363235203338310D0A363236203339340D0A363237203430360D0A363238203431370D0A363239203432380D0A363330203433380D0A363331203434380D0A363331203435360D0A363331203436330D0A363331203436390D0A363330203437330D0A363330203437370D0A363330203437380D0A363239203437390D0A363238203437390D0A363238203437390D0A363238203437390D0A363238203437390D0A363032203234370D0A363031203234370D0A353939203234390D0A353937203235310D0A353934203235340D0A353930203235360D0A353836203235380D0A353830203236300D0A353733203236300D0A353635203236310D0A353535203236300D0A353434203236300D0A353333203235380D0A353232203235370D0A353131203235350D0A353032203235330D0A343934203235310D0A343837203234390D0A343832203234370D0A343738203234350D0A343735203234330D0A343733203234310D0A343733203234300D0A343733203233390D0A343733203233390D0A343734203233390D0A343734203233390D0A373736203431370D0A373736203431370D0A373735203431380D0A373735203431380D0A373734203431380D0A373733203431360D0A373732203431340D0A373730203431300D0A373639203430360D0A373637203430320D0A373635203339360D0A373632203339300D0A373630203338320D0A373537203337340D0A373533203336350D0A373439203335350D0A373434203334350D0A373430203333350D0A373335203332340D0A373331203331330D0A373237203330320D0A373232203239310D0A373139203238300D0A373135203236390D0A373132203235370D0A373038203234350D0A373035203233340D0A373032203232320D0A363939203231300D0A363937203139390D0A363935203138380D0A363934203137370D0A363934203136370D0A363934203135360D0A363935203134370D0A363936203133380D0A363938203133300D0A373032203132320D0A373036203131350D0A373130203130390D0A373136203130340D0A3732342039390D0A3733332039360D0A3734342039330D0A3735372039320D0A3736392039330D0A3738322039350D0A3739362039370D0A383038203130310D0A383232203130350D0A383334203131300D0A383435203131350D0A383534203132310D0A383632203132380D0A383638203133360D0A383733203134340D0A383736203135320D0A383738203136300D0A383739203136380D0A383739203137370D0A383738203138350D0A383736203139330D0A383733203230310D0A383639203230380D0A383634203231340D0A383539203232300D0A383531203232350D0A383432203232380D0A383330203233300D0A383137203233310D0A383032203233310D0A373837203232390D0A373733203232370D0A373633203232350D0A373538203232330D0A373536203232330D0A373536203232330D0A300D0A34310D0A39330D0A3132300D0A';

        //  Bonus:
        //      if you will need to keep SigString size down, rather use PHP's gzdeflate or anything similar
        //      just don't forget if you later pull the compressed sig data from eg. database, to decompress it before sending it to SVG function
        //  $sigdecgz = gzdeflate($sigdec,9);

//      you can use these echos to see sample SigString
//      echo 'Printing decompressed SigString ; SetSigCompressionMode(0) :<br><br>';
//      echo $sigdec;

//      print the output of sigstring2svg, so my sample "AP" SigString, shown in SVG format, using slightly modified Scott's code
        echo '<br><br>Printing output of sigstring2svg() function, SigString as SVG (of decompressed & unencrypted signature !):<br><br>';
        echo sigstring2svg($sigdec);
        echo '<br><br>';

?>

OK, done with PHP ... but there is one more bonus for you folks!
I re-used same PHP code to actually draw the signature in HTML5 canvas, similar as the original SigWeb component does, but without using Topaz APIs/components.
I've re-used the PHP code to do the initial hex2bin and slicing
It is somewhat shorter this way, though not as polished as Scott's SVG.
Tested, works all nice even on combination of Ubuntu / Apache / PHP web server, with Android phone as client, so no Windows involved.

<script type="text/javascript">
    //  LuxZg - 08.05.2020.
    function cCanvas()
        {

            <?php

                //  sample signature, this SigString is hardcoded for example, you'd probably pull it from a database on server, hence PHP still makes sense for this step
                $sg = $sigdec;

                //  short version of PHP code

                //  convert hex to bin
                $raw = hex2bin($sg);
                //  cleanup double new-line after hex2bin conversion (\r\n)
                $raw = str_ireplace(array("\r",'\r'),'', $raw);
                //  exploding cleaned string to array
                $arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $raw);
                //  slicing coords to it's array
                $coords = array_slice($arr, 2, $arr[0]);
                    //  doing json encode to convert PHP array to JS array
                    $js_array_a = json_encode($coords);
                    //  echoing it as JS
                    echo "var coords = ". $js_array_a . ";\n";
                //  slicing line endings to it's array
                $lines = array_slice($arr, ($arr[0] + 2), $arr[1]); //Separate off number of coordinates pairs per stroke
                    //  and convert and echo to JSON as JS array for this as well
                    $js_array_b = json_encode($lines);
                    echo "var lines = ". $js_array_b . ";\n";

                //  server side done

            ?>

            //  now short client side JavaScript code

            //  define canvas that has HTML id = "c"; use any id just don't forget to change where needed
            var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
            //  and canvas' context
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            //  get the coords array length
            var arrayLength = coords.length;
            //  initialize variables used in for loop
            var coordx = '';
            var coordy = '';
            var tocoords = [];

            //  putting coordinates/lines on canvas

            //  for all coordinates in the coords array
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    //  we split each coordinate to X & Y, can be shortened, this is for readability
                    tocoords = coords[i].split(" ");
                    coordx = tocoords[0];
                    coordy = tocoords[1];

                    //  if we encounter coord that is mentioned in lines[] array
                    //  it means line END, so we make a MOVE instead of drawing line, using moveTo() that coordinate
                    if (lines.includes(String(i)))
                        {
                            context.moveTo(coordx, coordy);
                        }
                    //  otherwise, we DRAW the line between points on canvas, using lineTo() that coordinate
                    else
                        {
                            context.lineTo(coordx, coordy);
                        }
                }

            //  at the end we have to define the color of the signature in the canvas
            context.strokeStyle = "#000000";    //  black
            //  and the thickness of the line, as you feel appropriate
            context.lineWidth = "3";
            //  and finally tell browser to make our lines into stroke, which is effectively command that shows signature in the canvas
            context.stroke();

            //  this ends client-side code, and we need just some basic HTML markup to execute it
        }

</script>

<br>
<div style="color:red; font-size:25px;" onclick="javascript:cCanvas()">Click to show signature</div>
<br>
Canvas is below, press button to show signature:
<br>
<canvas name="c" id="c" height="600" width="1500" ></canvas>
<br>

<!--
Canvas is fixed size, which is the unpolished part.
Edit - proposed solution:
I found this post to crop canvas, works well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22267731/13312932
So you could start with empty no-size HTML5 canvas like so:
    <canvas id="c" />
Copy and add the function from that other answer and place it before my own *function cCanvas()*
 (you can ommit last 3 lines for image generation/tab opening)
And after defining *var canvas* temporarily expand it to really big canvas like so:
    // resize canvas temporarily
    canvas.width = 2000;
    canvas.height = 2000;
And then just after *context.stroke();* call the crop function like so:
    cropImageFromCanvas(context);
That's it, no surplus whitespace around signature, no guessing sizes, etc.
I will push new version to my GitHub later today/tomorrow for complete code.
-->
```

Comment: I have uploaded new version containing PostScript and PDF creation, as well as including the HTML5 canvas resizing/cropping via mentioned function. Due to constraints of article size, those are available at GitHub together with expanded version of this answer, and some companion files : https://github.com/luxzg/Topaz

Answer (score 1):

The SigWeb SDK provides a method to get the signature string in a image format. Using that image, its possible to generate the target Base64 string. Here's a vb.net based implementation.

```
 Dim sigImage As System.Drawing.Image
 Dim sigObj As Topaz.SigPlusNET
 sigObj = New Topaz.SigPlusNET
 sigObj.SetSigCompressionMode(1)

 sigObj.SetSigString(sigWebSignatureString)
 sigObj.SetImageFileFormat(2)
 sigObj.SetImageXSize(100)
 sigObj.SetImageYSize(80)
 sigObj.SetImagePenWidth(1)
 sigObj.SetJustifyMode(5)
 sigImage = sigObj.GetSigImage()
 Using ms As New MemoryStream()
 System.Drawing.Image.Save(ms, Format)
      Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
      Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
 End Using
```