# Convert Bitmap String into Base64 image

Tags: javascript, topaz-signatures

I am using Topaz Sigidp1. They have one API which returns a bitmap string. From there website https://www.topazsystems.com/Software/sigidp1.pdf,

```
GetBmpString()
(returns ascii hex string of bmp fingerprint--useful for web applications to send fingerprint image across
the web)
```

Now I have this string. How can I convert this into a base64 image?

**Updated:** Here are the first few chars 93B2000004B8000009000500E4D69C820000000069006D006100670065000452E30B918FCE119DE30

Comment: What exactly is an `ascii hex string of bmp fingerprint`? How do these strings look like? Can you add a sample? Like, the first 100characters or so, to get an idea what we're talking about

Comment: @Thomas I have added. I dunno is this is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520141/convert-topaz-sigweb-sigstring-to-base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another build from the Topaz support team which has this built-in feature (base64 image).